Trying to get JSON data from an API but getting an error when I try to concat in a while loop
I am trying to get data from a specific table (https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/dataset/yizn-abxn) on the the Centers for Medicare & Medicaid Services website using their API.
Because the API only provides 500 rows per request, I am using a while loop.
However, my concat isn't working for some reason. I tried googling for a solution, but the results didn't really help.
Below is my code.
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/query/yizn-abxn/0"

def loop_json():
    i = 0
    total_rows = 1500
    want = []
    json_norm = []

    while i < total_rows:
        size = 500
        offset_url = f"{url}?size={size}&offset={i}"
        print(offset_url)
        offset = i
        offset_response = requests.request("GET", offset_url)
        print(f"Made request for {size} results at offset {i}")
        # if you want to save the data you would do that here
        json_resp = offset_response.json()
        json_norm = pd.json_normalize(json_resp['results'])
        # want = pd.concat(json_norm)

        i += size
    return want

df = loop_json()

The function currently works if want = pd.concat(json_norm) is commented out, but it only gives me the last 242 rows.
Obviously, I would like the function to give me all 1,242 rows.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially since I am new to Python, JSON, and APIs.

You are not aggregating the results of your api calls. Perhaps you wanted to call concat with at least two parameters...

pd.concat()'s first argument takes a list of DataFrames to concatenate.
want = pd.concat([want,json_norm], ignore_index=True)

You will need to initialise want as an empty DataFrame first, rather than a list:
want = pd.DataFrame()

Each iteration of the loop will update want with the data in json_norm. ignore_index=True is  not necessary but will number the index 0-1241.

Thanks, worked perfectly. Guess I need to learn how to initialize correctly. And now I know to use a list in the first argument for pd.concat()
